# ArgumentException when binding a ListBox to an ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

First I should add that I am new to Windows Phone development, so go easy on me :-)

I want to bind a ListBox to an ObservableCollection < LinkElement > where each LinkElement is represented by a UserControl called Tile. So far the code works, I get as many Tile:s as I have LinkElement:s in my ObservableCollection (I have simplified the code below a little, there is just one LinkElement right now).

XAML:

```
        <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10,10,10,10">
        <ScrollViewer Name="linkScrollViewer">
            <ListBox Name="linkList" Margin="26,0,26,0" Height="380" >
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Controls:Tile>
                            <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                                <toolkit:ContextMenu Name="ContextMenu" >
                                    <toolkit:MenuItem Name="Edit" Header="Edit" Click="EditItem_Click"/>
                                    <toolkit:MenuItem Name="Delete"  Header="Delete" Click="DeleteItem_Click"/>
                                </toolkit:ContextMenu>
                            </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                        </Controls:Tile>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>                
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
```

I set the binding source through code :

```
linkList.ItemsSource = LinkProjection.List;
```

And the collection I bind against (that right now doesn't do much):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SoftTeam.SoftLink
{
 public class LinkProjection
{
    private Links _links;
    public ObservableCollection<LinkElement> List = new ObservableCollection<LinkElement>();
    public LinkProjection(Links links)
    {
        _links = links;
    }

    public void Refresh()
    {
        List.Clear(); 

        var element = new LinkElement();

        element.Name = "Button1"; 
        element.Header = "Media";
        element.Height = 200;
        element.Width = 480;
        element.IsLink = false;
        element.Tag = null;
        element.URL = "";

        List.Add(element);
    }
}

public class LinkElement
{
    public string Name;
    public string Header;
    public string URL;
    public double Height;
    public double Width;
    public bool IsLink;
    public object Tag;
}
```

}

The problem is when I try to bind properties of the Tile control to properties of the LinkElement class, I get an System.ArgumentException "Value does not fall within the expected range.". The exception gives me no hint on where the problem is since it doesn't occur in my code.

That is, when I change

```
<Controls:Tile> // This works!
```

in the XAML to for example

```
<Controls:Tile TileHeader="{Binding Path=Header}"> // This crashes
```

or

```
<Controls:Tile Name="{Binding Path=Name}">  // This crashes too
```

the exceptions occur. It does not matter which property I bind to, it gives an Exception. Without an properties bound, the code works fine.

I guess my question is : WHY?

Comment: I think you should use these properties inside a Model class which implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` Interface. Then you can bind these properties to XAML controls. Check this link for more info [link](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Data_Binding_to_controls_on_Windows_Phone)

Comment: I added INotifyPropertyChanged to the LinkElement-class and implemented it as in the link you sent, but now I am getting a NullReferenceException:

A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: I am investigating that now, not sure if that has anything to do with my original problem...

Comment: Nope, that was another problem, which means that the main problem still stands...

Comment: Ok, another update. INotifyPropertyChanged did work, but so far just for numerical properties (double in my case). It still fails on string and bool properties...

Comment: New update : 
Without a doubt, this is because of the fact that I am trying to bind to a UserControl. If I replace <Controls:Tile> with a <Button> I can easily bind to both bool and string variables. The story continues...

Comment: I finally found the answer in this article:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19072197/binding-properties-of-user-control-in-windows-phone-application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer in this article:

[Binding properties of User Control in Windows Phone Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19072197/binding-properties-of-user-control-in-windows-phone-application)

The problem was that my UserControl was in another project/assembly and I therefor needed to create Dependency Proeperties for my control.